# Apple Mach-O linker Error relating to ShareKit

Tags: ios, xcode, git, sharekit, mach-o

Thank you for reading this. I am trying to rebuild/reskin an iOS app. I just started at this job and everyone who originally worked on it is gone so I am a little stuck on this error I am getting.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DefaultSHKConfigurator", referenced from:

      _OBJC_CLASS_$_C3SHKConfig in C3SHKConfig.o

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKConfiguration", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in C3AppDelegate.o

  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_DefaultSHKConfigurator", referenced from:

      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_C3SHKConfig in C3SHKConfig.o

    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: 
    error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I have done some searching on this issue and I can see that the common solution has to do with git. I have found `"git submodule init, git submodule update"`. It makes sense to me why that would work however the project I am working on was not using git. I got it sent to me as .rar and I unpacked it. It was missing a lot of files from ShareKit, I replaced them. I even removed all of share kit and tried setting it back up. Thank you for your help

Comment: ShareKit has changed a lot over the time, you might have a very old version. Is share kit implemented in submodules, or those files are included directly within your app's target?

Comment: They are within the app's Target. C3 2013 >Flavour Conference> Helpers>Share>Classes>ShareKit. In the Sharekit folder along with a lot of other thing, I do have the DefaultSHKConfigurator.h and SHKConfiguration.h files. the C3SHKConfig.m and .h files are in there as well but I don't see any .o files anywhere in the project. Thank you for your help

Comment: o files are compiled objects, they are not in the project. Those errors mean, that red files are not available to compiler. You need .m (implementation) files of those missing classes to be included in your app's target